# body skipped with `send-email`?

Tags: git

I created a patch for git like this:

```
git add .
git commit -m "make slash-rules more readable"
git format-patch master -1 HEAD
```

I then modified the file `0001-make-slash-rules-more-readable.patch` to something like this:

```
From de4a66a7f1fce4d231e3e70ca4ab2af3f8ed3cd3 Mon Sep 17 00:00:00 2001
From: ***
Date: Fri, 26 Apr 2019 15:58:24 +0200
Subject: [PATCH] make slash-rules more readable

gitignore.txt: make slash-rules more readable

Make all paragraphs valid, even if they are not read
in strict order. Make the paragraph for pattern without
slash better understandable. Add paragraph for pattern 
with slash. Be precise whenever a trailing slashes
would make a difference. Add some examples.

Signed-off-by: ***

---
 Documentation/gitignore.txt | 37 ++++++++++++++++++++++++-------------
 1 file changed, 24 insertions(+), 13 deletions(-)

diff --git a/Documentation/gitignore.txt b/Documentation/gitignore.txt
index b5bc9dbff0..3a6fb9117c 100644
--- a/Documentation/gitignore.txt
```

I was then finally sending it to the mailing list with

```
git send-email -1 --to=git@vger.kernel.org
```

and got as a result:

> /tmp/Oq_BDD_ldq/0001-make-slash-rules-more-readable.patch

Now the email was send to the list, however without the body. It starts with

```
---
 Documentation/gitignore.txt | 37 ++++++++++++++++++++++++-------------
 1 file changed, 24 insertions(+), 13 deletions(-)

diff --git a/Documentation/gitignore.txt
```

In addition `/tmp/Oq_BDD_ldq/0001-make-slash-rules-more-readable.patch` does not exists and `0001-make-slash-rules-more-readable.patch` is still inside the git folder, although it should have been removed after the mail was sent.

Why is the file still in place (and not in `tmp/` folder) and why is the body missing in the mail?

Comment: I avoid playing with the patches themselves, and just massage the cover letter if used.

Comment: @PhilipOakley I follwed the guidelines in https://git-scm.com/docs/SubmittingPatches/2.3.5 as far as I understood, the cover letter is only necessary if the commit message does not speak for itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by placing the patch file to a specific folder like this:

```
git format-patch -o ~/patches/ -1 HEAD
```

And then send it like this to me:

```
git send-email --to email@test.com ~/patches/0001-make-slash-rules-more-readable.patch
```

Another benefit of this method is that one may send the patch file multiple times. (if one doesn't give a specific path, the *.patch file would have been removed after `send-email`). Thus one may send it first to the own mail to check if the output is correct, and then send it to the list.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you accidentally sent an original copy from the temp directory, rather than the edited version that got saved in a different place.

You didn't say what editor you used or how the different paths were related. Checkout which directory you were in when you ran the command(s)

The slash rules have been confusing for a while, with numerous questions to the list over the years, so well done of going for the improvement.

Comment: I have doubled checked that I am in the right directory. I used `git send-mail`  again but this time only to my private mail - but still the same issue - the file remains in directory and sends a file without body. How does one figure out which file he is refencing? Is it possible to tell him to use the current one? Otherwise maybe its easiest to clone the repository one more time, do the changes and try it again. Thanks for the motivational words! :)

Comment: @Adam The other option is a virus scanner issue, as often the various temporary files are prepared in a temp directory and then renamed in place, which can be hijacked by virus scanners holding a lock on the files, especially in Windows where the lock/release mechanism isn't identical.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu and I do not have a virus scanner. Not sure why he was looking at the `/tmp` folder, but I found a way now by putting the patch file outside. Still thanks for your help!